# How to pass data to another view

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, pass-data, infoview

I'm working on a map which have some markers and I want to create an info view which will show an image and some text for each marker.

[image: map]

So, when I press the info button, it goes to a info view.

[image: map2]

I have this on the code:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    if control == annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView {

        performSegueWithIdentifier("showInfo", sender: data)

    }
}
```

But I want to pass the data from "locations" so I could show a image for each.

I need to do this in **Swift**.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add this method to your class if you do not have and then pass your data to destination view's data.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showInfo" {
        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! YourViewController
        //this will execute before next ViewController's viewDidLoad method
        destination.data = sender
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to override `prepareForSegue` function in your `viewController`:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if "showInfo" == segue.identifier {
           // Then pass your data
           let destController = segue.mapViewController as! YourViewController 
           destController.yourData = sender
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Connect the info button outlet to your `viewcontroller`. Then create `func` as follows:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if "YourSegue" == segue.identifier {
        // Then pass your data
    }
}
```